# Remesh a selected surface

Tags: mesh, modifiers, bmesh

Is there any modifier that allows me to remesh let's say a one selected surface (triangulation)? I'm working on complex boolean objects. The problem when I apply boolean operations the mesh gets nasty at some point and I need to remesh only parts of the resulted boolean. Later, I will use this mesh as an input to another software so I need a clean stl mesh that works for Finite Element. It could help if someone tells me a trick even around it. I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Triangulation helps a bit with boolean operation (that's what people say). Probably attach a simplified blend or screen with issue. Probably it can be solved in a different way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can!

with

[Boundary Aligned Remesh](https://github.com/jeacom25b/blender-boundary-aligned-remesh/blob/master/boundary_alinged_remesh.py)

- Go into Edit Mode
- Select the messy part of the mesh or just one face
- Press P to separate  the selection
- Switch to Object Mode and select the separated mesh
- Use boundary aligned remesh to recalculate a new triangle mesh (boundary verts will be saved to get a good welding with the source mesh)
- In Object Mode CtrlJ join both meshes together again  into one layer.
- Go into Edit Mode again and weld them with Merge by Distance.

Voila, you should have a  pretty good result now.  Optionally smooth it a little bit with "relax" using Relax.

Comment: Wow this tool is so fricking amazing, it fixes so many problems of mine. Finally brings blender remesher much closer to that of zbrush

Comment: Sadly though this isn't capable of merging meshes :( , would be great if you could add that

Comment: @Sidney, that's not really possible with this plugin. It operates over the entire mesh it's given, so it has no knowledge of any other meshes to merge with. You will have to do the final step that Oliver mentioned, that of doing a Merge by Distance to connect the vertices back up again.

Answer (score 3):

Remesh modifier does not have a function affecting only a specific group of vertices.

**A:** I don't think it is possible to Remesh only specific object faces.

Quite hard imagine how this "remeshed" part of model (vertex group) would be merged with original. I think it would result with much more artefact on surface - since it will mix two different topologies.